# Spark shuffle service on local shared dir with Ceph on kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, spark-shuffle

We run **Spark 3.X on kubernetes**, executor **pods share the same `readWriteMany` Ceph volume**.

So, all Spark workers write shuffle data on the same volume (I guess into different dirs), available for any worker.

On other side, Spark is sharing shuffle data over network.

**How can I configure Spark to use local volume to get shuffle data from other worker rather than using TCP download?**